# Using StringTokenizer to make pair of words

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I was stuck in a situation, where I have to make pairs of words from a string of line using StringTokenzier. But I am not sure how that class can give me that functionality.

Example : Input : "USA UK USSR China"
Output : "USA UK" "UK USSR" "USSR China"

StringTokenizer has only hasMoreElements () and hasMoreTokens(), how can we iterate over it to achieve the desired output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the previous and you are done:

```
String previous = tokenizer.nextToken();
while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
  String current = tokenizer.nextToken();
  String correctValue = previous + " " + current;

  previous = current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I was unable to think of previous = current step.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Javadoc for StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)?  It has examples as well.  What have you tried so far?

The tokenizer is used to split strings based on a predetermined token.  In your case, your token is a space (the default).

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test", " ");
 String prevToken = st.hasMoreTokens() ? st.nextToken() : "";
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     String currToekn = st.nextToken();
     System.out.println(prevToken + " " + nextToken );
     prevToken = currToken;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I was unable to think of previous = current step. I have looked at javadocs.